# Unable to locate correct driver after re-installing windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I've performed a clean installation of Windows 7. I then installed the UI update to fix resolution issues : Internal_VGA_Intel_64bit_8.15.10.2622

My Samsung model is ba68-05408a

The problem im now encountering is that I cannot connect to internet due to driver not available :

[image]

[image]

Where can I download the driver required ?

Clicking "update driver" does not work as I'm not connected.

I've tried WLAN_Intel_64bit_15.0.0.75, QCA_WLAN_Driver_1.0.0.1 but still I receive above issue. I'm just guessing really what driver I should use as I don't know the adapter version ?

Update :

Device details and results of search are below :

[image]
[image]

But for device search results there are multiple options. Which one should I use ?

Update2 :

I've tried 53240_sp53663.exe & sp57965.exe but still the wireless lan is not being recognised. I've re-started my machine each time I installed.

Here are the download locations : 
http://devid.info/mn/53240/Broadcom+4313GN+802.11b%2Fg%2Fn+1x1+Wi-Fi+Adapter
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-107849-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en

I'm using the correct version of the driver?

Update 3 :

So in the end I used broadcom_wifi_5.100.82.95-vista-7.zip downloaded from http://www.driversguru.com/hardwareid-PCI---VEN_14E4-_-DEV_4357-_-SUBSYS_04DB185F . wi-fi appears to be working as expected. I think this is a vista driver but at least I can now connect and so update if I decide to.

I found googling for the "hardware id" version for the driver useful in finding the download page : "subsys_04db185f broadcom driver"

Comment: You have a Broadcom chip not an Intel chip.  Based on the hardware id.

Comment: @Ramhound please see update

Comment: No;  That isn't the correct drive.  That is a LAN driver, except the device your trying to install, is a wireless chip it has no lan functionality infact.

Comment: @Ramhound please see update

Comment: The driver was also on Samsungs website

Comment: @ramhound how did you find it there? I tried the samsing sute

Comment: I found a samsung laptop with the broadcom 802.11 chip, downloaded their software, and downloaded the drivers for that model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your wireless card's driver here.  Two things you can do:

**Easiest Way:**
Go to Samsung's web site from another computer.  Arm yourself with a USB flash drive and download the driver from their web site onto it.

Sometimes, however, manufacturers do not have well oganized websites.  They either list every driver for every card they've ever used in that model series, a driver that is years out of date, or in some cases a driver that is just plain wrong.  In these cases, you'll need to identify which device is actually in your computer.  So you have to resort to the hard way of doing things.

**How To Identify An Unknown Device In Device Manager:**
Double-click the unknown device to bring up the properties page and go to the details tab.  Under the Property dropdown, select Hardware IDs.  In the value box, the top value in the list is the device's full PCI ID string.

The string will start with PCI\VEN_xxxx&DEVxxxx where VEN_ is the vendor ID, and DEV_ is the device ID.

[image]

Go to www.pcidatatabse.com and enter EITHER the vendor ID OR the Device ID (the site cannot search both).  Start with the Vendor ID first.  In the screenshot below, 8086 is Intel's vendor ID, and 1502 is an Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network Card.

Now that you know the exact make and model of the device, you can either download the correct driver from your laptop manufacturer's web site, or you can go directly to Intel's web site (in this case) and download the driver from them (my preferred course of action when possible.)

Comment: thanks "This is your wireless card's driver here." Where is the driver ?Should "here" be hyperlink ?

Comment: No link. I meant the screenshot in your post is your wireless card's property page.  I'd need to see your details page to know what driver it actually needed.

Comment: please see update

Comment: please see update, thanks! definitely a learning experience! :)

Comment: I would have gotten the driver directly from Broadcom's web site but bravo for getting it working.